# Get First 10 Objects from Array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I'm trying to create an array from the first 10 objects of another array but I get an error:

> Cannot assign value of type 'ArraySlice' to type '[AnyObject]'

```
var latitudeArray: [AnyObject] = []
var tenLat: [AnyObject] = []

func getSaved() {
    if (PFUser.currentUser()?.objectForKey("Latitude") == nil) {
        latitudeArray = []
    } else {
        latitudeArray = PFUser.currentUser()?.objectForKey("Latitude") as! [AnyObject]
    }    

    tenLat = latitudeArray.prefix(10)
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to turn your ArraySlice into an Array.

`tenLat = Array(latitudeArray.prefix(10))`

Answer (score 0):

you should cast implicitly to `[AnyObject]`

```
var latitudeArray: [AnyObject] = []
var tenLat: [AnyObject] = []

func getSaved() {
    if (PFUser.currentUser()?.objectForKey("Latitude") == nil) {
        latitudeArray = []
    } else {
        latitudeArray = PFUser.currentUser()?.objectForKey("Latitude") as! [AnyObject]
    }

    tenLat = [AnyObject](latitudeArray.prefix(10))
}
```